# DateTime error inserting to a Database from Visual Studio ADO (SqlException: varchar data type to datetime produced a value outside of range)

Tags: c#, database, wpf, linq, insert

I'm working with MVVM in WPF and I have ADO for the model to use the database connection.

Now I'm trying to save new Artikel to database from my project, and I'm getting a SqlException: The conversion of the varchar data type to datetime produced a value outside of range.

This error is the same if I use that value with DateTime.Now or doing a select from the same database table using another register that should be in the correct format. I also tried to use ToShortDateString, ToUniversalTime, Convert.ToDateTime to format the Date but nothing worked.

In the database this DateTime can't be null, and I can't set it to nullable because  it's a field from Sage Database that I can't modify.

If I don't specify that field value, it gives me a different error:
SqlException: The conversion of datetime2 data type to datetime produced a value outside of range.
The instruction was finished.

I really don't know how to insert a new Artikel with this problem.

Insert code:

```
//Getting another value from the table to try this format
Articulos articlePerData = (from t in contextDomoli.Articulos
                                            where t.CodigoEmpresa == 1
                                            select t).FirstOrDefault();
Articulos article = new Articulos()
{
    CodigoEmpresa = 1,
    CodigoArticulo = cost.RefDomoli,
    DescripcionArticulo = cost.Descripcio,
    TipoArticulo = tipoArticulo,
    CodigoAlternativo = EAN,
    C_DataCanviPreu = articlePerData.C_DataCanviPreu,
};
contextDomoli.Articulos.Add(article);
contextDomoli.SaveChanges();
```

[image: Database field]

Comment: From the exception you posted, I see that the type of the problematic column is the old `datetime` (and not `datetime2`), so it may be something that's related to its limitations. Try this: make the required `Articulos` .NET property a `string` type instead of `DateTime`, and then convert your DateTime value to string by using the standard format, e.g: `myDateTime.ToString("s");`

Comment: It's a problem for me to edit the .NET property. It's auto-generated from the Database (Sage, can't edit too). If I understood correctly your answer, I think its not viable in this case. I need some way to pass this DateTime value correct for the Database without editing types.

Comment: I've tried to save my date into a string value with that standard format, and then reconvert that into DateTime without editing the database. Its working now!  `code DateTime data = DateTime.Now; string strData = data.ToString("s"); data = DateTime.Parse(strData); `

Comment: it crashes again, the same error with the same code from the last comment, I really don't know why.

Comment: We finally found it, another worker set a datatrigger that is doing this insert crash... solved deactivating the trigger.